# How to make ssh port 22 not visible (using firewalld)

Tags: fedora, sshd, firewalld

I have a virtual machine out on the Internet running Fedora 27 and it gets pounded regularly on port 22 with bots attempting to log in.

I have disabled root logins to my machine but I'm tired of my logs getting filled. So I made `sshd` listen to another port and for good measure I told `firewalld` to block port 22:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-port=22/tcp
```

I thought that this would make port 22 unresponsive (and thus make my system look like it's not even there), but I get an immediate "Connection refused" when I connect to port 22 from another host.

How do I make it so that connection attempts to port 22 time out, rather than an immediate "Connection refused"?

I have been frustrated in my Google searching, as generally people are trying to troubleshoot `firewalld`/`sshd` problems.

Essentially, I want port 22 to disappear.

Comment: You could try setting a rule to quietly drop all packets sent to port 22.

Comment: Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/a/819005/311264

Comment: You normally get 'connection refused', when the port is open, but there is no service listening on that port. Was that the only 'firewall-cmd' command you had used? You did reload firewalld after running the command, right?

Comment: You are describing TCP/IP normal behaviour when the service is not there. The option is to add a DROP rule to port 22, but that will be an exception, not the rule. btw, I would prefer disabling ICMP echo-request than adding a drop rule to SSH to reduce bot scanning activity.

Comment: @haxxor yes, I did.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro Yes I know. This is not a TCP question but a firewalld question. On other ports (eg, 444) Linux nicely does not even respond, and hence the connection times out. I removed port 22 with firewalld, there's no longer a service listening there, and now I would like the system to not respond at all.

Comment: @Mioriin Your language is much more precise, but it is the answer to the question, "How do I make it so that connection attempts to port 22 time out...?" though lacking in specifics. It's those specifics that are precisely what I'm looking for. However I do think it's curious that removing the port implies a "Connection refused" response and not simply a timeout.

Comment: Install CSF firewall, It will prevent you to stop brute force attack on port 22.
https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html
https://gotechnies.com/configserver-security-firewall/

Comment: When you remove the port, any connection attempt is logged to let you know that someone tried to connect "but I sent them away because they were knocking on the wall instead of the door" to help troubleshoot connection problems. Issuing a DROP rule or suppressing echo, like @Rui F Ribeiro suggests, tells the logger to not tell you every single time someone knocks on the wall. (according to my understanding. I'm not a network tech ^_^; )

Comment: I am not very familiar with firewalld yet, but do you have multiple zones in your firewalld config?

Comment: @MikeS Maybe, in your firewall, SSH is not allowed through the definition of a port, but through the definition of a service. `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ssh` would disable it in that case. And don't forget to apply it with `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`.